# Smartphone won't connect to specific Wifi

Tags: wi-fi

my Smartphone(Oneplus 7) won't connect to the Wifi at home. Every other device connects perfectly to the Wifi and my Smartphone connects to every other Wifi.

The problem started with my old device(Oneplus 2), it suddenly didn't connect to the Wifi anymore. When I got my new device, at the beginning the phone connected to the Wifi, the next day (after all got synchronized from the old phone) it didn't connect to the wifi anymore. It gets stuck at "Obtaining IP address..."

Strangely, after 2-3 days the old device(Oneplus 2) can connect to the Wi-Fi again.

I've already tried to reset all network settings and I have already removed all saved networks. I've tried with a static IP but nothing worked.

Logcat Output below (1000 Lines)

Thanks in advance

Full Logcat:[Pastebin](https://pastebin.com/7RPLCjwd)

Interesting part(i think so):

```
12-27 16:26:08.860 22079 22079 I wpa_supplicant: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-CONNECTED - Connection to 18:d6:c7:ba:3c:c9 completed [id=0 id_str=%7B%22configKey%22%3A%22%5C%22Patauner+Privat%5C%22WPA_PSK%22%2C%22creatorUid%22%3A%221000%22%7D]
12-27 16:26:08.862  1198  1282 I EthernetTracker: interfaceLinkStateChanged, iface: wlan0, up: true
12-27 16:26:08.865  1065 22084 I LOWI-8.6.0.41: [LOWI-Scan] get_intf_mode: WLAN interface type 2, err 0
12-27 16:26:08.872  1931  1931 D DPMJ    : |SERVICE| DPM received action android.net.wifi.STATE_CHANGE
12-27 16:26:08.873  1931  1931 I DPMJ    : |SERVICE| sendWifiStatus - subType: 21 networkState: 0 softApState: 11 rssi=0 ssid= bssid=00:00:00:00:00:00 ipV4Addr= ifNameV4= ipAddrV6= ifNameV6=
12-27 16:26:08.873  1931  1931 D DPMJ    : |SERVICE| DPM received action android.net.wifi.STATE_CHANGE
12-27 16:26:08.874  1931  1931 I DPMJ    : |SERVICE| sendWifiStatus - subType: 21 networkState: 0 softApState: 11 rssi=0 ssid= bssid=00:00:00:00:00:00 ipV4Addr= ifNameV4= ipAddrV6= ifNameV6=
12-27 16:26:08.876  1198  1548 D ConnectivityService: registerNetworkAgent NetworkAgentInfo{ ni{[type: WIFI[], state: CONNECTING/CONNECTING, reason: (unspecified), extra: (none), failover: false, available: true, roaming: false]}  network{252}  nethandle{1085737455629}  lp{{InterfaceName: wlan0 LinkAddresses: []  Routes: [] DnsAddresses: [] UsePrivateDns: false PrivateDnsServerName: null Domains: null MTU: 0 TcpBufferSizes: 524288,1048576,4194304,524288,1048576,4194304}}  nc{[ Transports: WIFI Capabilities: NOT_METERED&INTERNET&NOT_RESTRICTED&TRUSTED&NOT_VPN&NOT_ROAMING&FOREGROUND&NOT_CONGESTED&NOT_SUSPENDED Unwanted:  LinkUpBandwidth>=1048576Kbps LinkDnBandwidth>=1048576Kbps SSID: "Patauner Privat"]}  Score{20}  everValidated{false}  lastValidated{false}  created{false} lingering{false} explicitlySelected{false} acceptUnvalidated{false} everCaptivePortalDetected{false} lastCaptivePortalDetected{false} clat{null} }
12-27 16:26:08.877  1198  1606 D ConnectivityService: NetworkAgentInfo [WIFI () - 252] EVENT_NETWORK_INFO_CHANGED, going from null to CONNECTING
12-27 16:26:08.879  1931  1931 D DPMJ    : |SERVICE| DPM received action android.net.wifi.STATE_CHANGE
12-27 16:26:08.880  1931  1931 I DPMJ    : |SERVICE| sendWifiStatus - subType: 21 networkState: 0 softApState: 11 rssi=0 ssid= bssid=00:00:00:00:00:00 ipV4Addr= ifNameV4= ipAddrV6= ifNameV6=
12-27 16:26:08.882  1198  1224 D WifiStateMachine: send CMD_GET_CONFIGURED_NETWORKS
12-27 16:26:08.897  1198 22095 D ApfFilter: (wlan0): begin monitoring
12-27 16:26:08.900  1198 22096 D DhcpClient: Receive thread started
12-27 16:26:08.909  1198  1606 D ConnectivityService: NetworkAgentInfo [WIFI () - 252] EVENT_NETWORK_INFO_CHANGED, going from CONNECTING to CONNECTING
12-27 16:26:08.910  1198  1606 D ConnectivityService: getDefaultDataSubscriptionId, sub id = 1
12-27 16:26:08.915  1198  4174 V LocSvc_HIDL_Subscription_jni: wifi_supplicant_status_update
12-27 16:26:08.915  1198  4174 V LocSvc_HIDL_Subscription_jni: [wifi_supplicant_status_update][686] [HC] =>> [HS]
12-27 16:26:08.915   764   764 V LocSvc_HIDL_IzatSubscription: [wifiSupplicantStatusUpdate][675] [HS] <<<<= [HC]
12-27 16:26:08.916  1198  4174 V LocSvc_HIDL_Subscription_jni: Exit Result 0
12-27 16:26:08.919  1198  1224 D WifiStateMachine: send CMD_GET_CONFIGURED_NETWORKS
12-27 16:26:08.924  1198  1606 I chatty  : uid=1000(system) ConnectivitySer identical 20 lines
12-27 16:26:08.924  1198  1606 D ConnectivityService: getDefaultDataSubscriptionId, sub id = 1
12-27 16:26:08.926  1198 22091 D DhcpClient: Broadcasting DHCPDISCOVER
12-27 16:26:08.928 27631 27631 D WifiSettings: onAccessPointsChanged (WifiTracker) callback initiated
12-27 16:26:08.929  1198  1224 D WifiStateMachine: send CMD_GET_CONFIGURED_NETWORKS
12-27 16:26:08.930  1198  1277 E BatteryExternalStatsWorker: no controller energy info supplied for bluetooth
12-27 16:26:08.931  1198  7038 D WifiStateMachine: send CMD_GET_CONFIGURED_NETWORKS
12-27 16:26:08.933  1198  7038 D WifiStateMachine: send CMD_GET_CONFIGURED_NETWORKS
12-27 16:26:08.935  1198  3444 D WifiStateMachine: send CMD_GET_CONFIGURED_NETWORKS
12-27 16:26:08.937  1198  3444 D WifiStateMachine: send CMD_GET_CONFIGURED_NETWORKS
12-27 16:26:08.941  1198  1270 D BatteryStatsService: @@@@ awaitUninterruptibly in 24 ms
12-27 16:26:08.941  1198  1270 D BatteryStatsHelper: ===processSingleAppUsage===
12-27 16:26:08.945 27631 27631 D WifiSettings: onAccessPointsChanged (WifiTracker) callback initiated
12-27 16:26:08.946 27631 27631 I chatty  : uid=1000(system) com.android.settings identical 4 lines
12-27 16:26:08.946 27631 27631 D WifiSettings: onAccessPointsChanged (WifiTracker) callback initiated
12-27 16:26:09.115 27631 27631 E ndroid.setting: Invalid ID 0x00000000.
12-27 16:26:09.121  1198  3444 D WifiStateMachine: send CMD_GET_CONFIGURED_NETWORKS
12-27 16:26:09.121  1198  1606 D ConnectivityService: getDefaultDataSubscriptionId, sub id = 1
12-27 16:26:09.153  1198  1606 I chatty  : uid=1000(system) ConnectivitySer identical 20 lines
12-27 16:26:09.154  1198  1606 D ConnectivityService: getDefaultDataSubscriptionId, sub id = 1
12-27 16:26:10.733   768   808 E ANDR-PERF-MPCTL: Invalid profile no. 0, total profiles 0 only
12-27 16:26:10.766  1198  1478 V AlarmManager: Triggering alarm #0: 2 when =194417731 package =android operation = null listenTag =DhcpClient.wlan0.KICK flags =0x9
12-27 16:26:10.767  1198 22091 D DhcpClient: Broadcasting DHCPDISCOVER
12-27 16:26:11.160 27631 27631 W RenderThread: type=1400 audit(0.0:8798): avc: denied { map } for path="/dev/__properties__/u:object_r:vendor_default_prop:s0" dev="tmpfs" 
ino=15819 scontext=u:r:system_app:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:vendor_default_prop:s0 tclass=file permissive=0
12-27 16:26:11.160 27631 27631 W RenderThread: type=1400 audit(0.0:8799): avc: denied { map } for path="/dev/__properties__/u:object_r:vendor_default_prop:s0" dev="tmpfs" ino=15819 scontext=u:r:system_app:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:vendor_default_prop:s0 tclass=file permissive=0
12-27 16:26:11.160 27631 27631 W RenderThread: type=1400 audit(0.0:8800): avc: denied { map } for path="/dev/__properties__/u:object_r:vendor_default_prop:s0" dev="tmpfs" ino=15819 scontext=u:r:system_app:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:vendor_default_prop:s0 tclass=file permissive=0
12-27 16:26:11.171 27631 19120 E libc    : Access denied finding property "persist.vendor.fps.history.enabled"
12-27 16:26:11.173 27631 19120 E libc    : Access denied finding property "persist.vendor.hwui.skia.multithread.enabled"
12-27 16:26:11.173 27631 19120 E libc    : Access denied finding property "persist.vendor.hwui.skia.reduce.overdraw.enabled"
12-27 16:26:11.190 27631 27631 W RenderThread: type=1400 audit(0.0:8801): avc: denied { map } for path="/dev/__properties__/u:object_r:vendor_default_prop:s0" dev="tmpfs" ino=15819 scontext=u:r:system_app:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:vendor_default_prop:s0 tclass=file permissive=0
12-27 16:26:11.190 27631 27631 W RenderThread: type=1400 audit(0.0:8802): avc: denied { map } for path="/dev/__properties__/u:object_r:vendor_default_prop:s0" dev="tmpfs" ino=15819 scontext=u:r:system_app:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:vendor_default_prop:s0 tclass=file permissive=0
12-27 16:26:11.208 27631 19120 E libc    : Access denied finding property "persist.vendor.hwui.skia.multithread.enabled"
12-27 16:26:11.208 27631 19120 E libc    : Access denied finding property "persist.vendor.hwui.skia.reduce.overdraw.enabled"
12-27 16:26:11.253  1923  1923 D QcrilMsgTunnelIfaceManager: handleMessage what = 1
12-27 16:26:11.255  1923  1923 I QcrilOemhookMsgTunnel: [0]invokeOemRilRequestRaw: serial=1869 length=25
12-27 16:26:11.257  1923  2014 I QcrilOemhookMsgTunnel: [0]processOemHookResponse serial no: 1869 error: 0length=0
12-27 16:26:11.257  1923  1923 D QcrilMsgTunnelIfaceManager: handleMessage what = 2
12-27 16:26:12.410  1198  7038 I WifiService: getWifiServiceMessenger uid=1000
12-27 16:26:12.414  1198  1547 D WifiService: New client listening to asynchronous messages
12-27 16:26:12.431  1198  1548 D WifiConfigStore: Writing to stores completed in 10 ms.
12-27 16:26:12.432 27631 27644 D DecorView: onWindowFocusChangedFromViewRoot hasFocus: true, DecorView@6aeb7d4[Settings$WifiSettingsActivity]
12-27 16:26:12.433  1198  3444 D WifiStateMachine: send CMD_GET_CONFIGURED_NETWORKS
12-27 16:26:12.445   751 22086 E WifiHAL : Few pkt stats messages missed: rcvd = 288, prev = 0
12-27 16:26:12.445   751 22086 I WifiHAL : Fate Tx-Rx: Packet fate stats stop received
12-27 16:26:12.445 22079 22079 I wpa_supplicant: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED bssid=18:d6:c7:ba:3c:c9 reason=3 locally_generated=1
12-27 16:26:12.448  1198  1282 I EthernetTracker: interfaceLinkStateChanged, iface: wlan0, up: false
12-27 16:26:12.449 22079 22079 E wpa_supplicant: eap_proxy: eap_proxy_notify_config
12-27 16:26:12.449 22079 22079 I chatty  : uid=1010(wifi) /vendor/bin/hw/wpa_supplicant identical 1 line
12-27 16:26:12.449 22079 22079 E wpa_supplicant: eap_proxy: eap_proxy_notify_config
12-27 16:26:12.450  1198  1282 I EthernetTracker: interfaceLinkStateChanged, iface: wlan0, up: false
12-27 16:26:12.453  1198  1548 E WifiVendorHal: stopRssiMonitoring(l.2440) failed {.code = ERROR_NOT_AVAILABLE, .description = }
12-27 16:26:12.453  1198 22091 D DhcpClient: doQuit
```

Comment: i bet the problem is more related to router than client. maybe you will find something useful for keywords https://www.google.com/search?q=CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED+reason=3

Comment: please try with WPA2-AES-only instead of WPA/WPA2 compatible mode. another workaround seems to disable IEEE 802.11n when running in WPA mode

Comment: @alecxs it's running in WPA2 AES-only, I have tried with 11bg instead of 11bgn, but didn't work eighter. I think the problem is caused by google backup.

Comment: WPA2 seems to require 11n-only